# Limit values between two points on an arc?

Tags: javascript, canvas

I'm trying to adapt the code from a [previous question on circular dial controls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9017536/circular-range-selection-control). The concept is pretty similar to this one, except I would like to define a range in which the dial cannot be selected. Consider the volume controls/dials in hardware; they often have these 'dead zones' where they can't be turned:

[image: Volume control]

How can I replicate this in JavaScript? Here's the adapted code so far:

```js
function Dial(size) {
    var dial = this;
    var canvas = document.querySelector('#c');
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    var pi2 = Math.PI*2;

    this.from = 0.75 * Math.PI;
    this.to = 0.25 * Math.PI;
    this.value = this.from;

    var radius = size / 2 - 10;

    this.draw = function() {
        ctx.save();
        ctx.clearRect(0,0,size,size);
        ctx.translate(size/2,size/2);

        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.strokeStyle = "silver";
        ctx.lineWidth = 2;
        ctx.arc(0, 0, radius, this.from, this.to);
        ctx.stroke();

        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.lineWidth = 1;
        ctx.fillStyle = "green";
        ctx.strokeStyle = "black";
        ctx.arc(-radius*Math.sin(this.value),
                -radius*Math.cos(this.value),
                8, 0, 2*Math.PI);
        ctx.fill();
        ctx.stroke();
        
        ctx.restore();
    };

    var getMousePos = function(canvas, evt) {
        return {
            x: event.pageX - canvas.offsetLeft,
            y: event.pageY - canvas.offsetTop
        };
    };

    var inBounds = function(pos) {
        return Math.hypot(
            size / 2 - radius * Math.sin(dial.value) - pos.x,
            size / 2 - radius * Math.cos(dial.value) - pos.y
        ) <= 8;
    };

    canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", function(evt) {
        var pos = getMousePos(canvas, evt);
        if (dial.markerMoving) {
            if (pos.x == size/2 && pos.y == size/2)
                return;
            dial.value = Math.atan2(size/2-pos.x,size/2-pos.y);
        }
        dial.draw();
    }, false);

    canvas.addEventListener("mousedown", function(evt) {
        var pos = getMousePos(canvas, evt);
        dial.markerMoving = inBounds(pos);
    }, false);

    canvas.addEventListener("mouseup", function(evt) {
        dial.markerMoving = false;
    }, false);

    this.draw();
};

new Dial(150);
```

```html
<canvas id="c"></canvas>
```

Bonus points if you can work out how to display a 'range' on the selection - from the starting point on the dial to the selection point.

Comment: I don't understand your question.  You want us to write a clicky knob for you?  Just round off and redraw, or animate to the closest click when the user lifts the mouse button.

Comment: @RobertHarvey No, I want to create a 'dead zone' where the dial does not go to. In other words it should not rotate through the full 360 degrees but between the two points specified; `dial.from` and `dial.to`. I'm struggling a bit here with how I can compare these two values to what is returned by the `atan2` function.

Comment: Have you figured out how to turn the knob yet?

Comment: Drag the circle on the snippet ;-)

Comment: No, that's not what I mean.  You'll need to adjust the way the knob turns to simulate detents.

Comment: Your mouse move never checks bounds.

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl Right, that's what I'm struggling with. How do I compare the `dial.from` and `dial.to` points to what is returned by the `atan2` function? (which ranges from -π to π)?

Comment: Find the current angle and check if the current value is along the arc. Try checking `to -> from` instead of `from -> to`.

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl Thanks, figured it out from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out it was pretty straightforward, using `Math.abs`.

```js
function Dial(size) {
    var dial = this;
    var canvas = document.querySelector('#c');
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    var pi2 = Math.PI*2;

    this.from = 0.75 * Math.PI;
    this.to = 0.25 * Math.PI;
    this.value = this.from;

    var radius = size / 2 - 10;

    this.draw = function() {
        ctx.save();
        ctx.clearRect(0,0,size,size);
        ctx.translate(size/2,size/2);

        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.strokeStyle = "silver";
        ctx.lineWidth = 2;
        ctx.arc(0, 0, radius, this.from, this.to);
        ctx.stroke();

        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.lineWidth = 1;
        ctx.fillStyle = "green";
        ctx.strokeStyle = "black";
        ctx.arc(-radius*Math.sin(this.value),
                -radius*Math.cos(this.value),
                8, 0, 2*Math.PI);
        ctx.fill();
        ctx.stroke();
        
        ctx.restore();
    };

    var getMousePos = function(canvas, evt) {
        return {
            x: event.pageX - canvas.offsetLeft,
            y: event.pageY - canvas.offsetTop
        };
    };

    var inBounds = function(pos) {
        return Math.hypot(
            size / 2 - radius * Math.sin(dial.value) - pos.x,
            size / 2 - radius * Math.cos(dial.value) - pos.y
        ) <= 8;
    };

    canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", function(evt) {
        var pos = getMousePos(canvas, evt);
        if (dial.markerMoving) {
            if (pos.x == size/2 && pos.y == size/2) {
                return;
            }
            var radians = Math.atan2(size/2-pos.x,size/2-pos.y);
            if (Math.abs(radians) < dial.from) {
                dial.value = radians;
                dial.draw();
            }
        }
    }, false);

    canvas.addEventListener("mousedown", function(evt) {
        var pos = getMousePos(canvas, evt);
        dial.markerMoving = inBounds(pos);
    }, false);

    canvas.addEventListener("mouseup", function(evt) {
        dial.markerMoving = false;
    }, false);

    this.draw();
};

new Dial(150);
```

```html
<canvas id="c"></canvas>
```

Comment: BTW, The `Math.hypot` (proposed by ECMAScript6) is not supported in IE so you might want to shim `hypot` if you're supporting IE.